# Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS expected "base" to be absolute path to a valid directory

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, compiler-errors

I'm trying to set a background image on my react app.

when I tried to import the image with react and set the styles in the JSX it worked, but when trying to put it directly in the scss it shows this error.

this is the CSS:
[image: CSS]

and this is the error I get:
[image: error]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

url encoding in sass converts your space to '%20' that doesn't exist in the real url. so space doesn't work in scss. I think it's a bug. you can use '-' instead of space in the word 'Home Page'.
[image]